# How to implement stripe accordion layout with react js?

Tags: reactjs, stripe-payments

I want to implement the stipe Accordion payment layout. But couldn't implement this. I have implemented the Tab layout. But couldn't do the Accordion. I'm not getting to the point where I should use the `paymentElement` .

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const { resolve } = require("path");
// Replace if using a different env file or config
const env = require("dotenv").config({ path: "./.env" });

const stripe = require("stripe")(process.env.STRIPE_SECRET_KEY, {
  apiVersion: "2022-08-01",
});

app.use(express.static(process.env.STATIC_DIR));

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  const path = resolve(process.env.STATIC_DIR + "/index.html");
  res.sendFile(path);
});

app.get("/config", (req, res) => {
  res.send({
    publishableKey: process.env.STRIPE_PUBLISHABLE_KEY,
  });
});

app.post("/create-payment-intent", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const paymentIntent = await stripe.paymentIntents.create({
      currency: "EUR",
      amount: 1999,
      automatic_payment_methods: { enabled: true },
    });

    // Send publishable key and PaymentIntent details to client
    res.send({
      clientSecret: paymentIntent.client_secret,
    });
  } catch (e) {
    return res.status(400).send({
      error: {
        message: e.message,
      },
    });
  }
});

app.listen(5252, () =>
  console.log(`Node server listening at http://localhost:5252`)
);
```

Client:

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

import { Elements } from "@stripe/react-stripe-js";
import CheckoutForm from "./CheckoutForm";
import { loadStripe } from "@stripe/stripe-js";

function Payment() {
  const [stripePromise, setStripePromise] = useState(null);
  const [clientSecret, setClientSecret] = useState("");
   
   useEffect(() => {
    fetch("/config").then(async (r) => {
      const { publishableKey } = await r.json();
      setStripePromise(loadStripe(publishableKey));
    });
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch("/create-payment-intent", {
      method: "POST",
      body: JSON.stringify({}),
    }).then(async (result) => {
      var { clientSecret } = await result.json();
      setClientSecret(clientSecret);
    });
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      <h1>React Stripe and the Payment Element</h1>
      {clientSecret && stripePromise && (
        <Elements stripe={stripePromise} options={{ clientSecret }}>
          <CheckoutForm />
        </Elements>
      )}
    </>
  );
}

export default Payment;
```

checout:

```
import { PaymentElement } from "@stripe/react-stripe-js";
import { useState } from "react";
import { useStripe, useElements } from "@stripe/react-stripe-js";

export default function CheckoutForm() {
  const stripe = useStripe();
  const elements = useElements();

  const [message, setMessage] = useState(null);
  const [isProcessing, setIsProcessing] = useState(false);
  

  const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    if (!stripe || !elements) {
      // Stripe.js has not yet loaded.
      // Make sure to disable form submission until Stripe.js has loaded.
      return;
    }

    setIsProcessing(true);

    const { error } = await stripe.confirmPayment({
      elements,
      confirmParams: {
        // Make sure to change this to your payment completion page
        return_url: `${window.location.origin}/completion`,
      },
    });

    if (error.type === "card_error" || error.type === "validation_error") {
      setMessage(error.message);
    } else {
      setMessage("An unexpected error occured.");
    }

    setIsProcessing(false);
  };

    const paymentElement = elements.create('payment', {
      layout: {
       type: 'accordion',
        defaultCollapsed: false,
        radios: true,
      spacedAccordionItems: false
     }
   });

  return (
    <form id="payment-form" onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <PaymentElement id="payment-element"/>
      <button disabled={isProcessing || !stripe || !elements} id="submit">
        <span id="button-text">
          {isProcessing ? "Processing ... " : "Pay now"}
        </span>
      </button>
      {/* Show any error or success messages */}
      {message && <div id="payment-message">{message}</div>}
    </form>
  );
}
```

I have tried this. But it's not working.

```
const paymentElement = elements.create('payment', {
      layout: {
       type: 'accordion',
        defaultCollapsed: false,
        radios: true,
      spacedAccordionItems: false
     }
   });

  

return (
    <form id="payment-form" onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <PaymentElement id="payment-element" options={{paymentElement }}/>
      <button disabled={isProcessing || !stripe || !elements} id="submit">
        <span id="button-text">
          {isProcessing ? "Processing ... " : "Pay now"}
        </span>
      </button>
      {/* Show any error or success messages */}
      {message && <div id="payment-message">{message}</div>}
    </form>
  );
```

Answer (score 3):

Where you currently have this line:

```
<PaymentElement id="payment-element" options={{paymentElement }}/>`
```

You'll want to update that and include your desired Payment Element options in `options` there, so that would look roughly like this:

```
<PaymentElement id="payment-element" options={{layout: {type: "accordion", ... }}/>`
```

Alternatively you can store your desired options in a variable and then pass that into `options`:

```
  const paymentElementOptions = {
    layout: "accordion"
  }

  return (
    <form id="payment-form" onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <PaymentElement id="payment-element" options={paymentElementOptions} />
    ...
  )
```